# About existence of a finite subcover of $\mathbb C^2\setminus 0$ satisfying some conditions

Tags: complex-analysis

> Suppose that $\{U_\alpha\}$ is a family of open subsets of $\mathbb C^2\setminus 0$ whose union is all of $\mathbb C^2\setminus 0$. Show that there is a finite number of indices $\alpha_1,\cdots,\alpha_n$ such that for every point $v$ in $\mathbb C^2\setminus 0$ there is a complex number $z$ for which $zv$ is in one of $U_{\alpha_1},\cdots, U_{\alpha_n}$.

---

My thought:

To be honest, I have no idea about this question. I only know some single variable complex analysis, but nothing can be applied to $\mathbb C^2$ from what I have learned. Can someone give me a hint? Thank you.

Comment: This is equivalent to the complex projective plane, $\mathbb CP^2,$ being compact.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $S^3 = \{ (u,w) \in \mathbb C^2 \mid \lvert u \rvert^2 +  \lvert w \rvert^2 = 1\}$ be the unit sphere in $\mathbb C^2 = \mathbb R^4$ which is a compact subset of $\mathbb C^2_* = \mathbb C^2 \setminus \{ 0 \}$. $\{U_\alpha\}$ is an open cover of $S^3$, hence there exist $\alpha_1,\dots,\alpha_n$ such that $S^3 \subset U = \bigcup_{i=1}^n U_{\alpha_i}$.

Given $v =(u,w) \in \mathbb C^*$, we define $z = 1/\sqrt{\lvert u \rvert^2 + \lvert w \rvert^2} \in \mathbb R \subset \mathbb C$. Then $zv = (zu,zw)$ and $\lvert zu \rvert^2 +  \lvert zw \rvert^2 = 1$, thus $zv \in S^3 \subset U$, i.e. $zv \in U_{\alpha_i}$ for some $i$.